# Export infragistics grid data to excel

Tags: model-view-controller, infragistics

I need to export data from infragistics grid to excel and we are using mvc also.I got the code but what it does is loop through each record and then form the excel, which leads to poor performance.But what i want is it should bind the grid data at once like we do in  asp.net.

I went through lots of sites including Infragistics one but everywhere same code. Is there any way to achieve that?

below is the code which am using right now

```
        int i = 1;
        foreach (Market item in collection)
        {
            currentWorksheet.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = item.gp_name;
            currentWorksheet.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = item.gp_MarketCode;
            currentWorksheet.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = item.gp_CountryName;
            currentWorksheet.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = item.gp_ISOCode;
            currentWorksheet.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = item.gp_EricssonOperationalModelEOM;
            currentWorksheet.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = item.gp_region_name;
            i++;


        }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachement; filename=Market.xlsx");
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        currentWorkbook.SetCurrentFormat(WorkbookFormat.Excel97To2003);
        currentWorkbook.Save(Response.OutputStream); 
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DataPresenterExcelExporter ?

```
DataPresenterExcelExporter  exporter = new DataPresenterExcelExporter ();
exporter.Export(Grid, FileName, WorkbookFormat.Excel2007, Exportoptions);
```

Comment: No  I have not but if you can send me some link of example then i can try.Thanks i advance

Comment: Please refer the following links :
http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2013.1/CLR4.0/html/xamDataPresenter_Export_a_DataPresenter_Control_to_Excel.html
http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/47867.aspx